# How can i display an image returned as JSON

Tags: json

I want to call a web service that return an image as JSON. But i do not know how I can display the returned JSON as an image inside HTMl page.?

Best Regards

Comment: What does the returned JSON look like? How is the image contained within it? *(Surely these were fairly obvious pieces of information to include?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question leaves out some very important details, but assuming that the returned JSON has a string which is a base64-encoded image, you could use that string as the content of a [`data` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) as the `src` of an `img` element (assuming a [compatible browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)). More on using `data` URIs as images [here](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Example:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64," + dataFromServer.theImage;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ixaten/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ixaten/1/edit)

Of course, if the JSON contains a *link* to the image, you'd just use that link directly as `src` rather than using a `data` URI.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer; well to be honest , the web service is not ready yet, but i am trying to read and explore the available approaches to do the integration. As the web service is part of another system which is claiming that they will provide a web service to return images as JSON as part of the next release.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking something like below:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "gulmarg",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 5 ) return false;
    });
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/naZFw/6/)